# Azure cosmos dynamic query

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I need a help on to construct dynamic cosmos query using c#.
In cosmos database having name like "test.a'lcarte", so in the code we are trying to construct the dynamic query like

```
string _queryText = "SELECT distinct value c.createdby FROM c where c.createdby in(" + "'test.a\\'lcarte'" + ") and c.isactive!=false";
```

`'test.a'lcarte'` can be replace with input as string runtime.

this is output of _queryText :

```
SELECT distinct value c.createdby FROM c where c.createdby in('test.a'lcarte')
```

, looks like backslash() with apostrophe escpaing backslash and due to this string is not going correct format.

So my question is how to constrcut string using backslash with apostrophe.

Note :

```
SELECT distinct value c.createdby FROM c where c.createdby in('test.a\\'lcarte') and c.isactive!=false
```

, query working fine in cosmos query editor and my intention to pass or construct the same query dynamically in C# code.

Comment: If you want a backslash in your string you can either use two backslashes `\\ ` or use a verbatim string starting with `@` like  `@"'test.a\'lcarte'"`.

Comment: @GWimpassinger, Thanks your quick respone. It resolve the issue. I missed to add @ before the string. 
So i am using string.Replace("'", @"\'") as i have collection of strings and in that collection may have such data.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve a name containing special characters from a Cosmos collection, use `\\` instead of special characters or by using verbatim string `@` In the code below, the `Replace` function is used to escape single quotes in the input string by adding a backslash before them or verbatim `@` before the string.

**Using backslash `\\`**:

```cs
class Program
{
    private const string EndpointUrl = "****";
    private const string PrimaryKey = "****";
    private const string DatabaseId = "newDb";
    private const string ContainerId = "newCont";

    static async Task Main()
    {
        using (var cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(EndpointUrl, PrimaryKey))
        {
            var database = await cosmosClient.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(DatabaseId);
            var container = await database.Database.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(ContainerId, "/id");

            string userInput = await GetNameFromDbAsync(container.Container);
            string escapedInput = EscapeSpecialCharacters(userInput);

            string queryText = $"SELECT DISTINCT VALUE c.name FROM c WHERE c.name IN('{escapedInput}') AND c.isactive != false";

            await ExecuteCosmosDbQuery(container.Container, queryText);
        }
    }

    static async Task<string> GetNameFromDbAsync(Container container)
    {
        var query = new QueryDefinition("SELECT TOP 1 c.name FROM c");
        var resultSet = container.GetItemQueryIterator<dynamic>(query);
        var response = await resultSet.ReadNextAsync();

        string name = response.FirstOrDefault()?.name?.ToString();

        return name;
    }

    static async Task ExecuteCosmosDbQuery(Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Container container, string queryText)
    {
        var queryDefinition = new QueryDefinition(queryText);
        var resultSet = container.GetItemQueryIterator<string>(queryDefinition);

        while (resultSet.HasMoreResults)
        {
            var response = await resultSet.ReadNextAsync();
            foreach (var item in response)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }
    }

    static string EscapeSpecialCharacters(string input)
    {
        return input.Replace("'", "\\'");
    }
}
```

**Output:**
**`test.a'lcarte`**

**Using verbatim symbol**:

```cs
static async Task Main()
    {
        using (var cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(EndpointUrl, PrimaryKey))
        {
            var database = await cosmosClient.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(DatabaseId);
            var container = await database.Database.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(ContainerId, "/id");

            string userInput = await GetNameFromDbAsync(container.Container);

            string queryText = $@"SELECT DISTINCT VALUE c.name FROM c WHERE c.name IN('{EscapeSpecialCharacters(userInput)}') AND c.isactive != false";

            await ExecuteCosmosDbQuery(container.Container, queryText);
        }
    }

    static async Task<string> GetNameFromDbAsync(Container container)
    {
        var query = new QueryDefinition("SELECT c.name FROM c");
        var resultSet = container.GetItemQueryIterator<dynamic>(query);
        var response = await resultSet.ReadNextAsync();

        string name = response.FirstOrDefault()?.name?.ToString();

        return name;
    }

    static async Task ExecuteCosmosDbQuery(Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Container container, string queryText)
    {
        var queryDefinition = new QueryDefinition(queryText);
        var resultSet = container.GetItemQueryIterator<string>(queryDefinition);

        while (resultSet.HasMoreResults)
        {
            var response = await resultSet.ReadNextAsync();
            foreach (var item in response)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }
    }

    static string EscapeSpecialCharacters(string input)
    {
        return input.Replace("'", @"\'");
    }
```

**Output:**
**`test.a'lcarte`**

Comment: fyi the OP already resolved their issue, prior to your answer - just close-vote. Also, in the future, be sure to fix tagging (e.g. [tag:cosmos] needs to be removed, and replaced with [tag:azure-cosmosdb])

Comment: Ok... Sure David